# Trying to make a rounded box in html

Tags: html

For some reason I keep getting rectangles under my tables. Is there some way to test html without just meticulously scanning through?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"     style="background-color: #0C990A">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="14"><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner1.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>
                        <td width="172"></td>
                        <td width="14"><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner2.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="center" width = "14" height = "150">Blarzed.Thecom</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner3.gif" width="14" height="14"border="0" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner4.gif" width="14" height="14"border="0" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color: #0C990A">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="14"><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner1.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>
                        <td width="172"></td>
                        <td width="14"><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner2.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="..." /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="./images/layout/blarzedbanner.gif" width="600" height="150" border="0"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner3.gif" width="14" height="14"border="0" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="./images/layout/rounded_corner4.gif" width="14" height="14"border="0" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an ending "table" tag on the main wrapping table. One way to quickly figure out if you've got some type of typo or whatever would be to validate the HTML/XHTML via some type of tool. For instance:

http://validator.w3.org/

There are tools that will plugin to your browser like [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) and [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) that help in validation and debugging of HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

As a side note, I would forget doing tables and go with DIV tags and then apply the following CSS to any given DIV tag that you want rounded corners on. Here is your design re-done using DIV's and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rounded Corners Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .roundedContainer {
                background-color: #0c990a;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                float: left;
                height: 200px;
                padding: 0 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="roundedContainer" style="line-height: 200px;">Blarzed.Thecom</div>
        <div class="roundedContainer"><img src="/images/layout/blarzedbanner.gif" alt="Blarzed Banner"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code may require some tweaking, but that will get you half way there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Firefox extension.

There are plenty of ways to use it.  In your case, to see if the corners images are really loaded and rendered where you think they are, you can fire up firebug, navigate the DOM tree or even click on an area of your page to see what HTML elements are behind.